# python: how to strip lines efficiently from a matrix, which have elements appearing in other lines

Tags: python, matrix

```
list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 0, 6, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 2]
```

list is used "matrix like"

```
1. 0 1 2
2. 3 4 1
3. 5 0 6
```

... and so on. I would like to write all those lines into a new list/matrix, but without lines, that would repeat a number. **However the order of a line has to be preserved.**

So far I use this:

```
compa = [0,1,2,3,4,1,5,0,6,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,2]   #the list to be used as base
temp = [0,1,2]      #new list starts from the first element
temp2 = [12,13,2]   #new list starts from the last element
Mischzahl = 3       #defines the number of elements in a line of the "matrix"
n = 0
while n < len(compa):
    for m in range(0,len(temp)):
        if temp[m] == compa[n]:
            n = (int(n/Mischzahl) + 1) * Mischzahl - 1 #calculates the "foul" line and sets n to the next line
            break
        if (n + 1) % Mischzahl == 0 and m == len(temp) - 1 : #if the end of temp is reached, the current line is transferred to temp.
            for p in range(Mischzahl):
                temp.append(compa[Mischzahl*int(n/Mischzahl) + p])
    n += 1
```

and the same backwards

```
n = len(compa) - 1
while n > 0:    #same as above but starting from last element
    for m in range(len(temp2)):
        if temp2[m] == compa[n]:
            n = (int(n/Mischzahl) - 1) * Mischzahl + Mischzahl
            break
        if (n) % Mischzahl == 0 and m == len(temp2) - 1:
            for p in range(Mischzahl):
                temp2.append(compa[Mischzahl*int(n/Mischzahl) + p])
    n = n - 1
```

resulting output for temp and temp2:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 0, 6, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 2] #compa
[0, 1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]                              #temp
[12, 13, 2, 9, 10, 11, 5, 7, 8, 3, 4, 1]                   #temp2
```

Since this is the most time-consuming part of the script: Is there a more efficient way to do this? Any helpful advice or direction would be highly welcome.

Comment: Can you provide some sample inputs/outputs?

Comment: @JacobG. They're there already, aren't they?  From the last code block: `compa` is the input; `temp` and `temp2` the expected outputs.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a function that iterates over the list in strides of a given length (in your case 3), checks if the elements of the stride are in a set of numbers, if not extend the out list and update the set.

```
from math import ceil

def unique_by_row(compa, stride_size=3, reverse=False):
    strides = ceil(len(compa)/stride_size)
    out = []
    check = set()
    it = range(strides)
    if reverse:
        it = reversed(it)
    for i in it:
        x = compa[stride_size*i:stride_size*(i+1)]
        if not check.intersection(x):
            out.extend(x)
            check.update(x)
    return out
```

Tests:

```
compa = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 0, 6, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 2]

unique_by_row(compa)
# returns:
[0, 1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

unique_by_row(compa, reverse=True)
# returns:
[12, 13, 2, 9, 10, 11, 5, 7, 8, 3, 4, 1]
```

Comment: A couple of refinements: `check.update(x)` should work, and the `if` condition could be spelled `if not check.intersection(x):`.

Comment: thanks folks. I tested the solution and timed it a couple of times. It seems, it gives the results in roughly the same speed.

Comment: one more thing: "ceil" should be "math.ceil" with "import math", right? At least this is how I got it working on my machine.